# Troubles with Acrobat Reader within Firefox?

Tags: 10.10, firefox, 64-bit

I just built a new machine and installing Acrobat was last step in process. Am running Thinkpad X210 with 10.10 64-bit. I've always been able to reliably open PDFs inline from the web; however, when I launch a PDF, the main Firefox panel goes either white, completely black, or white with black diaganol streaks.

Perhaps this is video related... Here's what I have chipset wise

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

I'm certainly not wed to Acrobat, but I do want to have Firefox with inline PDFs from web.

Comment: screenshot please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to embed Evince, the default PDF reader, into Firefox. To do this install the [mozplugger](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mozplugger) package.

```
sudo apt-get instal mozplugger
```

You can then create a file in the '.mozilla' folder in your home folder called 'mozpluggerrc' and edit the contents to add the following:

```
application/pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-postscript: ps: PostScript file
application/postscript: ps: PostScript file
application/x-dvi: dvi: DVI file
    : evince $file
```

[Mozplugger Documentation](http://mozplugger.mozdev.org/documentation.html)

Comment: This was a good clue to making this work, but I found that I needed to instead modify /etc/mozpluggerrc instead...http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-view-pdf-files-online-in-firefox-on-ubuntu-9-10karmic

Comment: That's if you want this to be system wide.