# How to embed evince in firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, pdf, evince

I installed mozplugger and created the file mozpluggerrc with the following content according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22492/troubles-with-acrobat-reader-within-firefox/22523#22523) but when I open a .pdf it opens in a separate evince window.

is there a way I can truly embed it in Firefox like the chrome pdf reader?

```
application/pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-postscript: ps: PostScript file
application/postscript: ps: PostScript file
application/x-dvi: dvi: DVI file
    : evince $file
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Evince is a GTK+ PDF and PS viewer to replace gpdf/xpdf/acroread and ggv, and it's open source. Using mozplugger you can embed all sorts of stuff into Mozilla and/or Firefox like media players and openoffice.

First make sure you have Evince and mozplugger installed.

Now open up`~/.mozilla/mozpluggerrc` in your favorite text editor. Here's how to do it with gedit Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and paste

`gedit ~/.mozilla/mozpluggerrc`

Wherever you see this:

```
application/pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
```

and

```
application/x-postscript: ps: PostScript file
application/postscript: ps: PostScript file
```

add this on the next line:

```
repeat noisy swallow(evince) fill: evince "$file"
```

Close Firefox and Thats it!

HERE mine :

```
application/pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/pdf: pdf: PDF file
text/x-pdf: pdf: PDF file
application/x-postscript: ps: PostScript file
application/postscript: ps: PostScript file
    repeat noisy swallow(evince) fill: evince "$file"

# Also load the default configuration
sinclude(/etc/mozpluggerrc)
```

**Note : this plug-ins embed MPlayer Totem OpenOffice ... Too**

Comment: This not works to me. :-(
Firefox opens a new tab with PDF url and it opens a dialog to open PDF with evince/save/...

Comment: @Simón Try to install mozplugger package.