# Can Firefox open (embedded) PDF's without starting Okular?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, kubuntu, pdf, okular

How can I make Firefox on Kubuntu to open PDF in its embedded PDF viewer, like it does on Windows? Currently it opens PDF's in Okular. Some websites (with embedded PDF's) malfunction because of this behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [How to embed evince in firefox 4?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26796/43660)

Comment: I doubt it is a duplicate of that one. I just want to use the embedded PDF reader that comes with firefox since version 10 or 11 or so. Currently an external application (Okular) opens.

Comment: I'm not sure what embedded reader you're talking about.  Someone posted a link below to a beta plugin that is to be released in the next official release.  But AFAIK, before that, there is no official Firefox pdf plugin, only addons like from Adobe (which is supposed to be very slow) and the one mentioned in the answer I linked.  The Adobe one would not get packaged with the Ubuntu Firefox because it's proprietary.

Comment: Shoot! You are correct, I searched a bit in my Windows Firefox and found a 'Show Adobe Reader Toolbar'. Now I was really convinced Mozilla was packaging its own PDF reader, but I must have been reading a feature list of an upcoming release :(

Comment: If you wanted to be adventurous the latest nightly build of Firefox (Firefox 15) comes fully prepared with an inbuilt pdf reader.

Comment: v12 to 15 ... big step for mankind

Comment: ==> Firefox 19 automatically opens PDF's in a tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try installing PDF viewer addon in firefox
Here is the link:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs

Comment: I have installed it on Fx12 (beta) and it works. It isn't polished and won't open password-protected pdfs and falls flat on a few pages but it's certainly sufficient for most purposes. Plus we're helping test it and make it better :) . I notice you mentioned embedded pdfs. I'm not sure about those. Could you provide some links? Even Chrome's PDF reader had some initial issues with embedded PDFs.

Comment: [This](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe-pdf.html) embed works with Fx 12 and pdf.js

Comment: It works decently (on Firefox 11)... a bit slow, compared to Chrome's plugin, for example, but sufficient for most purposes.

Comment: And just one more link to an [embedded](http://biomedgerontology.oxfordjournals.org/content/64A/2/187.full.pdf+html) pdf that I think loads well with pdf.js.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the KDE viewer within Firefox, you can use the KParts plugin. To do this, install the [`kpartsplugin`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kpartsplugin) package. From the package description:

> This software implements a plugin for Netscape-compatible browsers in Unix environments. This plugin uses KDE's KParts technology to embed file viewers (e.g. for PDF files) into non-KDE browsers. Tested browsers include both (Mozilla Firefox and Opera, and is know to work with Chrome and Arora. With this plugin, you can e.g. view PDF files in Firefox using Okular as an embedded plugin.

Here I've opened a PDF document in Firefox using the embedded Okular KPart:

[image: KParts screenshot]