# firefox shows only blank screen when opening new pdf

Tags: firefox, pdf, plugins, adobe-reader

I use ubuntu 12.04 with firefox and adobe pdf plugin.
Since ubuntu 11.04 upto 12.04 i have the problem that i can open only one pdf file in the browser. After closing the pdf, firefox only shows a blank (black) screen when opening a new pdf.
Ridiculous: As long as i keep open the first pdf, i can open other pdfs. Otherwise it seems to crash...

I already tried reinstalling, but nothing changed.

Comment: I have installed the whole software: adobereader-deu (german version) from "partner" repository. The plugin was installed automatically.
Maybe I will change to Chrome, also because of the flash support, but at the moment I prefer firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem, and it [seemed to be reported as **bug** already](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/806605). You can [mark that it affects you, too](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/806605/+affectsmetoo) to increase its significance.

As **workaround** I recommend to open pdf files with Document Viewer/Evince as follows: Go to `Edit` → `Preferences` → `Applications`, search for "pdf" and choose `Use Document Viewer`:

[image: preferences dialog]

With the file it opens another window - but Evince is very fast and lightweight, so you won't experience serious performance losses.

---

[(how to embed Evince in Firefox with mozplugger)](https://askubuntu.com/a/22523/46531)

Comment: maybe the mozplugger plugin helps embedding evince. And maybe mozplugger also can solve the adobe plugin crash.

Comment: I've tried with the mozplugger on Ubuntu 12.04, but it only works sometimes. On other occasions I still get the black screen. I switched to evince.